# pivoting two column in pandas

Tags: machine-learning, python, pandas

How can I transfer two column features into pivot table on the following dataset

I have tried the **aggfunc** function but this fill the value either 0 or 1. I want to transfer the row as cell value.

Here is the dataset

```
content  Users  
22       1196
23       1196
23       1216
16       880
20       880
20       1224
22       1245
23       1122
22       872
```

I want to transfer this dataset into this

```
Users   1    2
1196    22  23  
1216    23  NaN
880     16  20
1224    20  NaN
1245    22  NaN
1122    23  NaN
872     22  NaN
```

I have tried it by using

`df.pivot_table(index=["city"], columns="cuisine", aggfunc=lambda x: 1, fill_value=0)`

> df.pivot_table(index=["users"], columns="content", aggfunc=lambda x: 1, fill_value=0)

But this fills the values either 0 or 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish what you want by doing:

> df.groupby('Users')['content'].unique().apply(pd.Series)

First, what you want is to groupby your values by users, to get all content values. Since you want unique ones, you can apply unique() built-in pandas function.

Then, since you will have a columns with a list of values, you can apply pd.Series to each row, to expand it into columns, by default, they are named from 0 to n, where n is the maximum length of a list, in this case, two.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a bit faster than using `apply`:

```
(df.assign(col=df.groupby('Users').cumcount())
  .set_index(['Users','col'])['content'].unstack())
```

Output:

```
col       0     1
Users            
872    22.0   NaN
880    16.0  20.0
1122   23.0   NaN
1196   22.0  23.0
1216   23.0   NaN
1224   20.0   NaN
1245   22.0   NaN
```